# How to disable vertical scrolling for div with position fixed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML && CSS layout:

```css
.circular-progress {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}

.inner-circle {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="section-matching-score" class="collapse show">
  <div class="circular-progress" style="background: conic-gradient(rgb(10, 207, 151) 288deg, rgb(238, 242, 247) 0deg);">
    <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    <p style="color:black; z-index: 100000; margin-top: 15px;">9/10</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
  scrollable div

</div>
```

The problem is that when I scroll down then it breaks my layout? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `position: fixed` with `position: absolute` and it works as expected.

```css
.circular-progress {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="section-matching-score" class="collapse show">
  <div class="circular-progress" style="background: conic-gradient(rgb(10, 207, 151) 288deg, rgb(238, 242, 247) 0deg);">
    <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    <p style="color:black; z-index: 100000; margin-top: 15px;">9/10</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
  scrollable div

</div>
```

Comment: in this example this will work but I'm using this in canvas so it will not work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why shouldn't this work in canvas? And why would you want the inner circle to be `fixed`, but the outer one not? You can also get there by adding `position: fixed` only on the `.circular-progress` (but keep the absolute part on the inner circle). If it's so different I the canvas-thing, then please post a full working example and not only a tiny fraction :D

Comment: I added a tiny fraction because I wanted to simplify the case a little bit but probably I will update my question.